# Google Compute Engine price when instance is shutted down

Tags: google-compute-engine

As Title, how much money is charged when a VM instance is shutted down? I would like to set up a backup site for my main site.

Answer (score 0):

When you stop an instance it goes in TERMINATED state.

When an instance is TERMINATED you will only pay for it's disk space.

Pricing details are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing).

Note that after starting up again instance with ephemeral IP may have a different address. It could be useful to reserve a static IP for web usage. 
Static IP cost will be billed only when instance is not running.

Sincerely,
P.